# How i can debug managed code when kernel debugger is enabled on my system?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, kernel, managed-code

I'm a windows kernel-mode (Driver) developer and for this purpose(Develop drivers and debug that ) i enabled kernel debugger on my system.
But when i want to debug a managed-code (A C# project) in my system, using `Visual Studio debugger` i receive the following error message:

```
Debugging isn't possible because a kernel debugger is enabled on the system
```

In this case what should i do ?? (I don't want to disable kernel debugging or use any other debugger instead of VS debugger).
Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cysxtck9.aspx) this is a known issue. If you upgrade your project to target .NET 4.0 or 4.5. it should work without disabling the kernel debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer : I'm not very expert in C# programming, if i want to upgrade my project it's will be difficult for me ?. (Excuse me if my English is bad)

Comment: It's simple, just right-click the project in solution explorer, choose properties and the target framework version is available as an option on one of the tabs.

Comment: Even when the target platform is below .NET 4, VS 2013 allows debugging in mixed mode with the kernel debugger is enabled.